# BigQuery: Resources exceeded during query execution. without any expensive operations

Tags: google-bigquery

I have 100TB of data which is not partitioned or clustered. I need to read in this data and store it to a partitioned table. The query itself is very simple it is something like following:

```
select * 
from `table_ref`
where id >= lower_bound and id <= upper_bound
```

Idea is to write all 100TB to partitioned table. I use destination table with partition property to achieve this. A single job to do this timed out after 6 hours limit. I am making each job handle smaller and smaller ranges down from 25TB, 9TB and finally 6TB however I am still seeing resource exceeding exception. Note that this query will still need to perform full table scan to find keys in ranges. There is no way to debug if the write size is the problem or full table scan is the problem.

Is there a better resource/tool to see what is actually going on so I can modify my approach to avoid resource exceeding exception?

Comment: does your job look something like: `bq --location=[LOCATION] query --destination_table [PROJECT_ID]:[DATASET].[TABLE] --time_partitioning_field [COLUMN] --use_legacy_sql=false 'select * from big_old_hoking_table_with_100TB'`?

Comment: Yes, using JobConfigurationQuery

Comment: It should work. I'd suggest posting the job id and maybe one of the Google engineers can have a look into it for you.

Comment: Please, if you have a support package open there a case providing the job ID. Otherwise, please open a private issue in the Public Issue Tracker with the project number and job id directly [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187164) and post here the issue number in order to be able to locate you and help you myself.